# InvalidTrack: [InvalidTrack] invalid track

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, youtube, spotify

I am trying to grab all the songs from a spotify playlist, then add the songs to a queue. But instead it is giving me that error. This is my current code that I am using:

```
else if (interaction.options.getSubcommand() === "splaylist") {

            // Search for the playlist using the discord-player
            let url = interaction.options.getString("url")

            const tracks = await getTracks(url).then(tracks => {return tracks}); //returns an array containing the first 100 songs in a playlist
            console.log(tracks); //tracks is the information of all of the tracks

            async function getResults(track){ // a function that is supposed to add every song in the tracks const to the queue by getting the name and artist and searching that
                const result = await client.player.search(track, {
                    requestedBy: interaction.user,
                    searchEngine: QueryType.AUTO
                })
                if (result.tracks.length === 0)
                    return await interaction.reply(`No playlists found with ${url}`)

                await queue.addTrack(result.track) //Adds the track to the queue
            }

            // (should) run the function for every single song
            await tracks.forEach(track => getResults(track.toString()));

        }
```

Full error message:

```
InvalidTrack: [InvalidTrack] invalid track
    at new PlayerError (E:\DiscordMusicBot\node_modules\discord-player\dist\Structures\PlayerError.js:28:15)
    at Queue.addTrack (E:\DiscordMusicBot\node_modules\discord-player\dist\Structures\Queue.js:235:19)
    at getResults (E:\DiscordMusicBot\commands\play.js:113:29)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  createdAt: 2022-09-23T14:48:21.556Z,
  statusCode: 'InvalidTrack'
}
```

Comment: What does the `getTracks()` function do? I'd assume the way you're passing the track from that function into `queue.addTrack()` is incorrect.

Comment: IMO the `youtube` tag isn't helpful for this question.